# How to Update the SetDatasource dynamically on crystal Report

Tags: windows, vb.net, crystal-reports

We are using Visual Studio 2015 & SAP crystal reports v13.

**Step 1:** I’m fetching the Query from the crystal report by using the GetCommandText()  function.

Following the code is GetCommandText() function.

```
Dim boReportDocument As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
Dim boReportClientDocument As CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ISCDReportClientDocument = boReportDocument.ReportClientDocument
Dim boReportClientDocument As CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ISCDReportClientDocument = boReportDocument.ReportClientDocument
Dim SqlQuery As String = ""
boReportClientDocument.RowsetController.GetSQLStatement(ISCRGroupPath, SqlQuery)
```

**Step 2:** I’m trying to concatenate the where condition into the SQL query.

**Step 3:** Then the Query is Execute and assigned to a dataset.

**Step 4:** And Set the Dataset value into the CrystalReport.setdatasource.

If I am trying to use the Specific field in the Select query for binding the crystal report, I am getting the attached error.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwX9f.png)

In the same condition if I am trying to change the Specific filed into **Select * From** the crystal report is loading correctly. But the **“where”** condition is not getting considered. The crystal report is loading all the data.

so here is how to update the query into the crystal report. The query is supporting in VB6 & not supporting in vb.net

Following the code is VB.net

```
Dim ReportDoc As New ReportDocument
Dim ConnectionString = "Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=testDB;User ID=sa;Password=123;"
ReportDoc.Load("~\CrystalReportTesting\CrystalReport1")
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)       
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con)
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dtset As New DataSet
adapter.Fill(dtset, "Dataset1")
ReportDoc.SetDataSource(dtset.Tables.Item(0))
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ReportDoc
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Following the Code is VB6

```
fReport.Report.SQLQueryString = fReport.Report.SQLQueryString & _
                            " where ""Invoice"".""Ref"" in (" & 1,2,3 & ") " & sqlOrderby
```

Comment: If anyone has an idea regarding the above issue please help me to resolve this